# wait for a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, multer

I coded a little website that takes your webcam applies a filter and displays this via a io.emit canvas.

It takes a photo every 40ms, edit's it and displays it again also every 40ms. Locally this works fine but on my server the uploading takes a bit longer ~100ms.

Now I have the problem, that my display function wait's for something and caches the images and displays them with lag.

If I end the livestream or open the canvas in another tab, it works fine.

Anyone has an Idea how could make the uploadToCanvas() function work in a different thread or make it non laggy?

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        
        cb(null, 'public/images/input');
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (path.extname(file.originalname).length > 0) {
            const extension = path.extname(file.originalname).substring(1).toLowerCase();
            if (['mp4', 'mov', 'avi', 'mkv'].includes(extension)) {
                cb(null, 'video' + path.extname(file.originalname));
                console.log('Saved video');
            } else {
                cb(null, 'image' + path.extname(file.originalname));
                console.log('Saved image');
            }
        } else {
            uploadToCanvas()
            if (!fs.existsSync(INPUTFRAME)) {
                console.log(file)

                cb(null, "frame.png")
                console.log("frame created success")
            }
            else {
                console.log("frame allready there" + i)
                i++
                cb(null, ".ignore")

            }
            
        }
    }
});
```

```
function uploadToCanvas() {
    fs.readFile(OUTPUTFRAME, function (err, buf) {           
                let imgData = buf.toString('base64');
                io.emit('update', { image: imgData });
        }
    });
}
```

I tried to use it the same way I use it locally (with almost 0ms upload) but it did not work. Big images lag more than small images to display on canvas.

Comment: sending base64 encoded images every 40ms is usually not a good solution.

Comment: A serverside filter? That's a lot of traffic _and_ a lot of processing power. Are you sure you can't do this clientside?

Comment: the server should only handle 1 client sending in images and it has enough processing power. It's used for styletransver

Comment: @ITgoldman how would you do it?

Comment: i dont know. you could lower the fps. you can lz compress it client side but not sure that's worth it. also, maybe irrelevant but you can stream peer to peer using WebRTC.